# Plesk correctly sending emails but unable to receive external emails

Tags: email, smtp, plesk, postfix-mta

Everything has been working good untill today, when we had an issue with our SSL certificate when it expired and we changed it for another.

Since that happened, we can properly send emails but not receive them, unless they are emails from our own domain.

- The installed SSL **is not a Wildcard SSL**.
- We have **not added the subdomain "mail.domain.com"** on the Plesk domains list.
- We **assigned the non Wildcard SSL to work also on email** on the Plesk domain settings.
- We have no information regarding the non-receiving emails on the Plesk logs.

If i go to the following SMTP tester: https://www.wormly.com/test-smtp-server and send an email **checking that it has to be an SMTP email**, then that email is received correctly even if it comes from a different domain.

By the other side, **if i do not check the SMTP email checkbox, the email is never received**

Our DNS records are the following:

```
domain.com. TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
smtp.domain.com. A SERVER.IP
pop.domain.com. A SERVER.IP
pop3.domain.com. A SERVER.IP
imap.domain.com. A SERVER.IP
domain.com. MX(1) mail.domain.com
```

What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It has been apparently been fixed after changing the MX record from "mail.domain.com" to "domain.com".

These DNS records have been working for a year since our last update, and the only thing that has changed is the SSL certificate. Im not really sure how this has been affected, maybe the previous SSL certificate was a Wildcard one, while this wasnt, and that made the email not receive properly.

Not really sure about this theory though, but it seems to work.